# how to exclude particular ajax call from ajaxComplete event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently, we are using ajaxComplete listener which is calling specific function which I mentioned after every ajax call happened.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

    someFunction();
})
```

There is one scenario that after specific ajax call,I want to do something instead of calling **someFunction()**.

Is there a way to exclude a specifc ajax call from ajaxComplete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is small example how you can use the settings argument in the $.ajaxComplete

```
$.ajax({    
type:"GET",
url:"http://google.com"
});

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://stackoverflow.com"
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,settings){
    console.log("URL",settings.url);
    if(settings.url === "https://stackoverflow.com")
    {
        $(".loadedPage").html("Stackoverflow loaded");
    }
    else if(settings.url === "http://google.com")
    {
        $(".loadedPage").html("Google Loaded");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

[See the jQuery docs for it](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

You are supplied with the event object, the XMLHttpRequest object and the settings object for each Ajax call. Use this to differentiate between your calls.